# Rails: restrict date_select to 30 days only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

Rails 3.0

I have a standard Web form that asks for a calendar date in the future and enters it into a date field in my model.

```
    <%= f.date_select :dayzero, :start_year => 2012, :end_year => 2012 %>
```

As you see, I've limited the HTML displayed to just 2012.

Can I insert options to dynamically restrict the Day / Month / Year fields to the next 30 days only?

So, on February 1, 2012,  a user would only see

1-31 in the Day field
February and March in the Month field
2012 in the year field.

Likewise, on September 15, a user would only see:

1-31 in the Day field
September and October in the Month field
2012 in the year field.

It's OK if the fields aren't --exact--  just close enough.

Thanks!